# Python Loop for temperature

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, for-loop

I am learning python for the first time and my assignment required me to:

> Write a loop to print all elements in `hourly_temperature`. Separate
> elements with a -> surrounded by spaces. Sample output for the given
> program:
>
> ```
> 90 -> 92 -> 94 -> 95
> ```
>
> Note: 95 is followed by a space, then a newline.

After playing I had difficulty and found the coded answer as:

```
hourly_temperature = [90, 92, 94, 95]

Htemp = len(hourly_temperature)

#create list
temps = []

if Htemp >= 0:
    for i in hourly_temperature: #question on i and appends i
        temps.append(i)
        temps.append('->')
        Htemp -= 1
        continue
temps.pop()
for s in temps:    #question here
    print(s,'', end='')
    continue
print('')
```

My question is regarding the for loops that I have notated with the #question.

I am wondering what the purpose is for the `i` and `s` to make the code work.

Comment: See https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F; any basic tutorial will explain how loops work.

Comment: It seems that this is not your code and you are trying to learn programming from it. I'm sure doing anything to learn is a good thing, but you can do better than this. This code is awful, there are many things which are not needed, you can find better resources for learning. Also, find some tutorial which explains what the code does, so you don't have to guess.

Comment: I never said this was my code, I stated I had difficulty and "FOUND" the coded answer. The part I was struggling with was adding the ->.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure many people here will give you 'Pythonic' one-liners that will output what you need.  But I think you're at the stage where you need to learn how to code logically, rather than how to be Pythonic.

The example you give is messy and not elegant in any language.

Here is how I would code your assignment, using simple logic suitable for a beginner.  Hopefully this will be more helpful than a short one-liner.

```
hourly_temperature = [90, 92, 94, 95]

# Start with an empty string
s = ""

# Step through each temperature in the list
for t in hourly_temperature:

    # If the string contains a number, then we need to add ->
    # before the next number.
    if s != "":
        s += "-> "

    # Add the temperature and a space
    s += str(t) + " "

# Print the string we have just built
print(s)
```

Another common way to achieve the result is to not worry about checking whether "-> " needs to be prefixed during the loop.  Instead, always prefix "-> " and remove the erroneous one at the end.  This is slightly more efficient for large loops.

```
hourly_temperature = [90, 92, 94, 95]

s = ""
for t in hourly_temperature:
    s += " -> " + str(t)

# At this stage, s contains " -> 90 -> 92 -> 94 -> 95" so we need to remove the first ->
# We do this by keeping everything from character 4 onwards
print(s[4:])
```

Comment: This was amazingly informative and really helpful, thank you! I am doing an internet class and it is only 8 weeks, it is so fast paced and rarely do I see things explained so well.

Answer (score 2):

`i` takes each value of `hourly_temperature`, as `s` takes the value of each element in `temps`.

This is a very complicated way to join values with a separator. Better to use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
hourly_temperature = [90, 92, 94, 95]
print(' -> '.join(map(str, hourly_temperature)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `i` and the `s` are going to be variables that represent the next value in the list every time the loop iterates. You need them to actually access each item.

You should try to rewrite your answer to only use one loop and avoid creating the second list `temps`

You should also be able to do this without using `Htemp`, `pop()`, or `continue`.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is very messy and can be made very small
For Example:

```py
hourly_temperature = [90, 92, 94, 95]
joined_temps = " -> ".join(map(str, hourly_temperature)) + " " # Add the temperatures together with " -> " as separaters and add the space as you said
print(joined_temps)
```

`"separater".join(typing.Union[list, tuple])` joins a list or tuple together separated by the given separater, then we add the space as you said

Then we print it because print already provides a newline at the end of the string

If you would like it a for loop form

```py
hourly_temperature = [90, 92, 94, 95]
ordered_temps = []
for temp in hourly_temperature:
    ordered_temps.append(temp)
    if not temp == hourly_temperature[-1]:
        ordered_temps.append(" -> ")
    else:
        ordered_temps.append(" ")
print("".join(map(str, ordered_temps)))
```

We are once using join again but this has no separater, so it will only join the list.